# Links to Help Center pages are serving up error pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges

Apparently all of the help center links are having trouble right now... except the actual help center page. I just happened to notice it on the Privileges page because that was the page I wanted to see.

This link from the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) is sending me to an error page. Technically, it's not really the help center that's the problem. The page just seems to be dead.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Apparently I'm not allowed to know how to use Stack Overflow. :(

Comment: Just tried the link again and I too get the error, nop back to working again.. Maybe 1 server somewhere giving the error.

Comment: looks like it's not just that page. All of the links on the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) seem to be broken. Click on any of them and it gives a similar error page

Comment: @DavisBroda Indeed... :/ Ugh. That's even worse.

Comment: Yeah, `/help` works, but anything `/help/somepage` is broken

Comment: The powers that be have decided that we are beyond help

Comment: Some devs are looking into the exceptions. Hang tight, please.

Comment: @TinyGiant it is part of the new quality project. In an A/B test we're going to see if posts get better if users don't have any help pages.

Comment: @rene Well, in that case they need to remove the help center entirely, not merely break the links :P It's more confusing to know that there is a help center but be denied the content than to not have one at all.

Comment: Seems okay to me. I can see those pages and the next pages. Maybe it's solved quickly?

Comment: @NVZ yeah... because they fixed it. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adam Lear [says](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6368260#6368260):

> well, help center stuff is partly my bad and partly some other failure we couldn't exactly identify where removing a redis key didn't propagate correctly to all web servers

As always, [blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/).